# Input value not changed when clicking div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the value of a input and submit it after clicking.
For some reason it is not submited.

The value inside the input increase or decrease when clicking the div, but it is not submitting.

When I change the value inside the input and offocus, it does save.

What am I missing here?

```
<div class="reduced items item-<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" onclick="
var result_<?php echo $item->getId() ?> = document.getElementById('qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>'); 
var qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?> = result_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>.value; 
if( !isNaN( qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?> ) &amp;&amp; qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?> > 1 ) result_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>.value--;
$(location.href='save').submit();
return false;">-</div>

<input type="text" name="quote_request[<?php echo $item->getId() ?>][qty][]" id="qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>" value="<?php echo $item->getQty()*1; ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" onchange="location.href='save'" class="required-entry validate-zero-or-greater input-text" maxlength="12" />

<div class="increase items" onclick="
var result_<?php echo $item->getId() ?> = document.getElementById('qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>'); 
var qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?> = result_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>.value; 
if( !isNaN( qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?> )) result_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>.value++;
$(location.href='save').submit();
return false;">+</div>
```

Comment: *What am I missing here?* - some formatting skills... dude - sort your formatting out, and you'll probably get some people be able to actually look at your code... O.o

Comment: That piece of code is unreadable. Please show us an example of the actual generated HTML, ideally a [mcve] I also have a strong suspicion that `$(location.href='save').submit();` won't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
First you should not mix your php/html/javascript code like in the way that you did.

Second, avoid put the id, or whatever another code value in the variable name, instead use an Array's with the key value equivalent to id.

Third, use functions, the easily way to see the problem that is occuring, is cleaning your code.

Your problem is because you are using location.href inside the jquery seletor, I dont know what is your form, but the correctly way to submit a form  is something like this:

```
function click_function_down(item_id) {
    var result[item_id] = document.getElementById('qty_' + item_id); 
    var qty[item_id] = result[item_id].value;
    if( !isNaN( qty[item_id] )
        && qty[item_id] > 1 ) {
            result[item_id].value--;
        }

    $('#yourform').submit();
    return false;
}

function click_function_up(item_id) {
    var result[item_id] = document.getElementById('qty_' + item_id); 
    var qty[item_id] = result[item_id].value;
    if( !isNaN( qty[item_id] ) ) {
            result[item_id].value--;
        }

    $('#yourform').submit();
    return false;
}
```

And the html code:

```
<form id="yourform" action="save">
<div 
class="reduced items item-<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" 
onclick="click_function_up(<?php echo $item->getId() ?>)">
-
</div>

<input 
type="text" 
name="quote_request[<?php echo $item->getId() ?>][qty][]" 
id="qty_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>" value="<?php echo $item->getQty()*1; ?>" 
size="4" 
title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" 
onchange="location.href='save'" 
class="required-entry validate-zero-or-greater input-text"
 maxlength="12" />

<div 
class="reduced items item-<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" 
onclick="click_function_up(<?php echo $item->getId() ?>)">
-
</div>
```

try this, and let me know if you could fix the problem.